# How do I resolve a Sqlite Error (1) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Im new to flutter and first time to work with sqlite database.
I have created a todo app that is linked to a Sqlite database. It has simple cards that i can add and it works fine. The problem is, I have a delete icon, but for some reason the cards do not delete when I press the delete icon. I get the following error message in the stack:

E/SQLiteLog(22653): (1) no such table: çustomerblueprint in "DELETE FROM çustomerblueprint WHERE id == ?"
E/flutter (22653): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: çustomerblueprint (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: DELETE FROM çustomerblueprint WHERE id == ?) sql 'DELETE FROM çustomerblueprint WHERE id == ?' args [1]

I have read for hours to try and fine a solution, but don't seem to get this one.

My code is:

**Database Code**

```
 class CustomerBluePrint {
 int? id;
 final String title;
 DateTime creationDate;
 bool isChecked;


 CustomerBluePrint({
 this.id,
  required this.title,
  required this.creationDate,
  required this.isChecked,

  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  return {
  'id': id,
  'title': title,
  'creationDate': creationDate.toString(),
  'isChecked': isChecked ? 1 : 0,
  
  };
  }


  @override
  String toString() {
  return 'CustomerBluePrint(id : $id, title : $title, creationDate : $creationDate, isChecked 
  : $isChecked )'; // , phone : $phone, mobile : $mobile, fax : $fax, email : $email, name : 
  $name)';
  }
  }


   class DatabaseConnect {
   Database? _database;

   Future<Database> get database async {

   final dbpath = await getDatabasesPath();

   const dbname = 'customerblueprint.db';

   final path = join(dbpath, dbname);

   _database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);

   return _database!;
   }


  Future<void> _createDB(Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute('''
  CREATE TABLE todo(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    creationDate TEXT,
    isChecked INTEGER
  )
 ''');

 }


  Future<void> insertCustomerBluePrint(
  CustomerBluePrint customerblueprint) async {

  final db = await database;

   await db.insert(
  'customerblueprint',
   customerblueprint.toMap(),
   conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );
   }


  Future<void> deleteCustomerBluePrint(
  CustomerBluePrint customerblueprint) async {
  final db = await database;

  await db.delete(
   'çustomerblueprint',
  where: 'id == ?',
  whereArgs: [customerblueprint.id],
  );
 }


 Future<List<CustomerBluePrint>> getCustomerBluePrint() async {
 final db = await database;

 List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = await db.query(
  'customerblueprint',
   orderBy: 'id DESC',
 ); 

 return List.generate(
  items.length,
  (i) => CustomerBluePrint(
    id: items[i]['id'],
    title: items[i]['title'],
    creationDate: DateTime.parse(items[i]['creationDate']),
    isChecked: items[i]['isChecked'] == 1 ? true : false,
    
  ),
);
}
}
```

****Customer List Code****

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'library.dart';
 import 'customer_card.dart';

 class CustomerList extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function insertFunction;
 final Function deleteFunction;
 final db = DatabaseConnect();
 CustomerList(
  {required this.insertFunction, required this.deleteFunction, Key? key})
  : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Expanded(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: db.getCustomerBluePrint(),
    initialData: const [],
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
      var data = snapshot.data;
      var datalength = data!.length;

      return datalength == 0
          ? const Center(
              child: Text('no data found'),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: datalength,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) => CustomerCard(
                id: data[i].id,
                title: data[i].title,
                creationDate: data[i].creationDate,
                isChecked: data[i].isChecked,
                insertFunction: insertFunction,
                deleteFunction: deleteFunction,
              ),
            );
           },
           ),
           );
           }
           }
```

**Customer Card Code**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    import 'library.dart';

    class CustomerCard extends StatefulWidget {
    final int id;
    final String title;
    final DateTime creationDate;
    bool isChecked;
    final Function insertFunction;
    final Function deleteFunction;

    CustomerCard(
    {required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.creationDate,
    required this.isChecked,
    required this.insertFunction,
    required this.deleteFunction,
    Key? key})
   : super(key: key);

   @override
  _CustomerCardState createState() => _CustomerCardState();
  }

  class _CustomerCardState extends State<CustomerCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var anotherCustomerBluePrint = CustomerBluePrint(
    id: widget.id,
    title: widget.title,
    creationDate: widget.creationDate,
    isChecked: widget.isChecked);
  return Card(
   child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
        child: Checkbox(
          value: widget.isChecked,
          onChanged: (bool? value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.isChecked = value!;
            });
            anotherCustomerBluePrint.isChecked = value!;
            widget.insertFunction(anotherCustomerBluePrint);
          },
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Text(
              DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm aaa')
                  .format(widget.creationDate),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xFF8F8F8F),
              ),
            )
          ],
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          widget.deleteFunction(anotherCustomerBluePrint);
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
      ),
      ],
      ),
      );
       }
      }
```

**Customer Code**
This is my Homepage

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
      import 'package:invoice_app/customer_profile.dart';
      import 'customer_list.dart';
      import 'library.dart';

      class Customer extends StatefulWidget {
      const Customer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
     _CustomerState createState() => _CustomerState();
      }

     class _CustomerState extends State<Customer> {
     

     var db = DatabaseConnect();
     void addItem(CustomerBluePrint customerblueprint) async {
     await db.insertCustomerBluePrint(customerblueprint);
     setState(() {});
     }

   void deleteItem(CustomerBluePrint customerblueprint)  async {
   await db.deleteCustomerBluePrint(customerblueprint);
    setState(() {

    });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF5EBFF),
     body: Column(
     children: [
      CustomerList(
        insertFunction: addItem, deleteFunction: deleteItem),

      CustomerProfile(
        insertFunction: addItem
      ),
     ],
      ),
     );
     }
```

The deletefunction is suppose to delete an entry based on the 'id'assigned to it. Everything works fine, except I cannot delete a card (entry) as it throws the error.

Please help. Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your mistake take a look at **Database Code** and implementation of the method `Future<void> deleteCustomerBluePrint(CustomerBluePrint customerblueprint)` You have an error there. Your:

```
  await db.delete(
   'çustomerblueprint',
  where: 'id == ?',
  whereArgs: [customerblueprint.id],
  );
```

Mine Repaired:

```
  await db.delete(
   'customerblueprint',
  where: 'id == ?',
  whereArgs: [customerblueprint.id],
  );
```

An error in the word **customerblueprint**, you do not have the letter "c" there, you have some other sign.

Comment: Hi Legend. Your name says it all! What an eye you have there! I would never have noticed. Anyway, After I corrected the mistake you highlighted, I had another problem. My database still did not recognized its name 'customerblueprint'. I eventually figured that in addition to the fault you highlighted that I had the incorrect database name in my data base code. I had the name 'todo' instead of 'customerblueprint'  CREATE TABLE todo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT. So, when I fixed the 'c' typo and corrected the database name, it all is working just fine.

Comment: Just lastly, continuing to my comment above. Others previously commented on my null safety problem I had on my Customer List Code above (the null operator !). The way the code is written was not wrong afterall. The problem was my typo on my database name and the incorrect database name that was used.

Comment: I enjoyed reading your answer :) But I would also like to ask you if you could mark the answer as "correct" (tick) if it helped you.